# Images not showing in applet in browser after updating java to version 51?

Tags: java, applet

It was working ok until I updated java to version 51. NoW it gives me a NullPOinter exception.
I am using `Aplet.class.getResource("image.jpg")` to load the image, but now it doesn't work.

I have Folder called Applets, inside are the .class files from the applets and Images folder and I have index.html file with this code

```
<applet codebase="Applets" code="Applet1"></applet>
```

Now this was working fine before the update

Comment: *"`Aplet.class.getResource("image.jpg")`"*  Try instead "`this.getClass().getResource("image.jpg")`"

Answer (score 1):

Is the image in the jar or are you loading it from the context of the page?
According to this blog: http://www.duckware.com/tech/java-security-clusterfuck.html
You should better use getResourceAsStream.

```
You must place all possible files inside the JAR, and use 
the Class.getResourceAsStream() calls to access. If you 
need to access any files outside the JAR, Oracle has 
screwed you over
```